# A state machine of a robot implemented through python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython

I am attempting to implement the state machine of a robot in Python. 
The robot behaves as follows:
When the switch is off, the robot does nothing;

When the switch is on:
By default, the robot moves forward

The robot constantly reads from the light sensors and uses this to track a line on the floor representing a "road". when the sensor reading is 40 or below, the sensor is off the road

If the sensor on the right leaves the road, the robot speeds up the right wheel to 75% until it returns to the road, then it returns the right motor to 50%;

If the sensor on the left leaves the road, the robot speeds up the left wheel to 75% until it returns to the road, then it returns the left motor to 50%.

If the bump sensor is triggered, the robot backs up at 100% speed for 1 second, then rotates clockwise 180 degrees and starts moving forward again at 50% on both motors.

My code is:

```
Robot = input("Turn on or off: ")
if Robot == "off":
  print("stayed off")
else:
  print("I am on and moving")
  while Robot:
    Robot= int(input("enter shine number. or turn off: "))
    if Robot=="turn off": ## THE problem is turn off is not a number so this is not working.
      break    
    if Robot >= 40:
      print("I stay on the road")
    elif Robot <40:
      Robot =input("right sensor leaves the road or the left? ")
      if Robot== "right":
        print("I speed up the right wheel to 75% until I return to the road, then I return the right motor to 50%")
      if Robot=="left":
        print("I speed up the left wheel to 75% until I return to the road, then I return the left motor to 50%.")
    Robot= input("trigger bumper sensor? or turn off: ")
    if Robot== "trigger":
      print("I back up at 100% speed for 1 second, then rotate clockwise 180 degrees and start moving forward again at 50% on both motors.")
    if Robot=="dont trigger":
      print("I stay on the road")
    if Robot=="turn off":
      break
```

How can I improve this code seeing what the state of the robot is?

Comment: can you not make "turn off" a flag or a default value like 0 or -1?

Comment: I dont know what you mean by making something a "flag". Do you mean doing. turnoff=0 or something? @okkhoy

Comment: `if Robot=="turn off": ## THE problem is turn off is not a number so this is not working.` for this line in your code, i suggested you make turn off an integer taking 0 / 1 or something similar. in effect creating a flag of sorts.

Comment: in any case can you explain what you mean by "How can I improve this code" its quite open ended i feel.